# Java modifiers syntax and format

Tags: java, syntax, coding-style

I find myself getting confused as to the order of access and non access modifiers. For example

```
abstract void go()  
abstract public void go()  
public final void go()  
void final go()  

final class Test{}  
class final Test{}  
final abstract class Test{}  
abstract final Test{}
```

I never know what the correct order is and sometimes I get it wrong because there are so many possible combinations. Is there a definite guide as to which should come before the other?

Is there any description of the format and order in which they are to appear in the code? I am trying to come up with a syntax guide but I am not sure if it is 100% correct. Here it is:

```
Methods:  
[access modifier | nonaccess modifier] return-type method-name  

Classes:  
[access modifier | nonaccess modifier] class class-name  

Interfaces:  
[access modifier | nonaccess modifier] interface interface-name       

Variables:  
[access modifier | nonaccess modifier] variable-type variale-name
```

Comment: There is no correct order, ergo not a real question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the official [**grammar**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) of the Java Programming Language (simplified):

```
Modifier:
  Annotation | public | protected | private
  static | abstract | final | native | synchronized
  transient | volatile | strictfp

ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration:
        {Modifier} (ClassDeclaration | InterfaceDeclaration)

ClassBodyDeclaration:
        {Modifier} MethodOrFieldDecl

MethodOrFieldDecl:
        Type Identifier MethodOrFieldRest
```

So, for classes and interfaces, the modifiers must **always** appear before the `class` keyword, and in any order. E.g., `final public class` is valid, but `class final` is not. For methods and fields, it is the same, but the modifiers must appear before the type.

Comment: Note: any order of modifiers is **valid**, but it is easier for people reading code if all the code in a project uses a consistent order. Because of this, there is a *customary* order [(see small-print sentence at end of Java spec 8.3.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1) that has been widely adopted, [e.g. by Google](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html#s4.8.7-modifiers); many java tools encourage this ordering.

Comment: Note that Java 8 adds `default` to interface method declarations: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-19.html#jls-19-9 which by the order in the grammar comes after `public` and `abstract`.

Answer (score 12):

See http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_modifier.html.

The correct (or rather, conventional) order is :

1. public
2. protected
3. private
4. abstract
5. static
6. final
7. transient
8. volatile
9. synchronized
10. native
11. strictfp

This order should come naturally to your mind after some days programming in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Just as in the English language, adjectives (modifiers such as `public`, `static`, `volatile`, etc) precede the noun they describe (`class`, `interface`, or any type such as `int` or `String`). The order of the modifiers doesn't matter to the language, but by reading code you'll quickly find which feel more natural.

Answer (score 2):

Modifiers go before the `class` or a type. According to the [Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.1) [Language](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1) [Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3), order between modifiers does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there's the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html), which explains all that is valid syntax in the language and there is also the [coding conventions used by Oracle/Sun](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), which is a bit old but still explains a lot of stuff.