# What would be the right way to declare qualifiers in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java modifiers syntax and format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050233/java-modifiers-syntax-and-format)

Is it `private static final` or `private final static`. I do understand that both of them work, but would like to know the order in which the spec declares it.

Comment: Seeing that both work, the spec is probably fine with either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The order of access modifiers doesn't matter. They just have to be *present*.

For method modifiers, the [Java language spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3) notes, that it is *it is customary,
though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown
above in the production for MethodModifier.*, which is:

```
(Annotation) public protected private abstract static final synchronized native strictfp
```

---

**Addition**

recommended order for field modifiers (as of [JLS 8.3.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1)):

```
(Annotation) public protected private static final transient volatile
```

recommended order for class modifiers (as of [JLS 8.1.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.1)):

```
(Annotation) public protected private abstract static final strictfp
```

*(Annotation)* is not a modifier, it's a placeholder for any annotation. Annotations should be put before any other modifier.

Comment: The *lava* language! I can't wait for that to come out :)

Comment: Saw it and fixed it while applying a link ref - Can't imagine why I typed `l` instead of `J` ;) (maybe because Java is *hot* :D )

Comment: +1: IMHO, Using a consistent order makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, but one of style.

I prefer `private static final`

Answer (score 1):

The spec in this case is the [§ 8.3 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3) and [§ 8.3.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1)

```
FieldDeclaration:
    FieldModifiersopt Type VariableDeclarators ;

FieldModifiers:
    FieldModifier
    FieldModifiers FieldModifier

FieldModifier: one of
    Annotation public protected private
    static final transient volatile
```

As you can see the order of the field modifiers can be anything you want. You can even mix annotations anywhere in there.

Comment: You're right, looks like he had fields in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The order I've most seen is `static final` and not `final static`.
When it is not part of your code convention then it is personal preference. But I would recommend to always write `static final` except for the case you're forced to write it the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what (if?) the spec says on the matter, but either one compiles.  Therefore, it comes down to coder preference!

Comment: Not necessarily. There are a lot of coding styles which do compile, but contradict with the [Sun/Oracle Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any preference mentioned in either direction in [the spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/jTOC.doc.html).

Comment: I do. See my post with a link ref.