# Difference between final static int and static final int?

Tags: java, static, final

Is there any difference between `final static int x = 1;` and `static final int x=1`? In other words, will the java compiler represent `x` in exactly same way in both the cases ?

EDIT: Is there any kind of precedence or priority the compiler has with regard to static and final?

Comment: In the first one you have `final` before `static` ;)

Answer (score 9):

There is no difference the compiler will represent them in the same way.

It is just personal preference, personally I use `static final` and this is what I generally see used by other developers.

Comment: There an [official style guide](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7050276/2071828) that says `static final` is the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

**There is no semantic difference.** From the JLS ([§8.3.1 Field Modifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1)):

> ```
> FieldModifier: one of
>      Annotation public protected private
>      static final transient volatile
> ```
>
> If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for FieldModifier.

Thus the preferred form is

```
static final int x=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

java compiler represents x in exactly same way in both cases

Answer (score 1):

No difference. I prefer to use `final static int`

Answer (score 0):

This is from the Java Language Specification [§8.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1):

`FieldModifier: one of
    Annotation public protected private
    static final transient volatile`

> If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field
>   declaration, **it is customary, though not required**, that they appear in
>   the order consistent with that shown above in the production for
>   FieldModifier.

So there is no difference between the two in your case. Only that `static final` is more customary.