# Is it legal to put annotation after access modifier in Java 7? Or Java 8?

Tags: java, annotations, java-8

This is usual code:

```
@Autowire
private Service service;
```

But with Java 7 this also works (and shorter):

```
private @Autowire Service service;
```

Is that legal in Java 8 (have same semantic)? Is that bad coding practice?

Comment: It's not really shorter, given that you can also write `@Autowire private Service service;`...

Comment: legal: yes.... good idead: i think not!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050233/java-modifiers-syntax-and-format

Comment: It is NOT shorter. The line is longer and harder to read.

Comment: @Gimby Idea that you have 40 declarations and 40 lines vs 80 is case. Then same modifiers written in same order on single line you just skip huge rectangle of code and look to field types and names!

Comment: @Oliver, true, but putting access modifiers first increases readability. I actually like the second way better even if it goes against recommendations in both annotation tutorial and JLS.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html)

In Java 7 :

> Annotations can be applied to declarations: declarations of classes,
>   fields, methods, and other program elements. When used on a
>   declaration, each annotation often appears, **by convention**, on its own
>   line.

As of the Java SE 8 release, annotations can also be applied to the use of types. :

Class instance creation expression:

```
new @Interned MyObject();
```

Type cast:

```
myString = (@NonNull String) str;
```

implements clause:

```
class UnmodifiableList<T> implements
    @Readonly List<@Readonly T> { ... }
```

Thrown exception declaration:

```
void monitorTemperature() throws
    @Critical TemperatureException { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

According to [official Java 7 grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) this is legal:

```
Modifier: 
  Annotation
  public
  protected
  private
  static 
  abstract
  final
  native
  synchronized
  transient
  volatile
  strictfp

ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration: 
  {Modifier} (ClassDeclaration | InterfaceDeclaration)
...
```

[Grammar for Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html) also seems to allow free mixing of modifiers:

```
MethodDeclaration:
    {MethodModifier} MethodHeader MethodBody 

MethodModifier:
    Annotation public protected private
    abstract static final synchronized native strictfp
```

Comment: Beside the fact that you are comparing the grammars for Java7 *class* declarations with the Java8 *method* declarations, there is no difference in the semantic of the two grammars. Both allow free mixing of annotations and modifier keywords.

Comment: @Holger I just copy what I find first from specs )) Save my time ))