# Is it possible to add qualifiers in @RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, lombok

If I wanted to use the annotation `@Qualifier` on a constructor dependency injection, I would have something like the following:

```java
public class Example {

    private final ComponentExample component;

    @Autowired
    public Example(@Qualifier("someComponent") ComponentExample component) {
        this.component = component;
    }
}
```

I know Lombok's annotations to reduce boilerplate code and don't have to include a constructor would be as follows: `@RequiredArgsConstructors(onConstructor=@__(@Inject))` but this only works with properties without qualifiers.

Anyone know if it is possible to add qualifiers in `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))`?

Comment: Already ask on github  https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/745

Comment: I also think it's something that isn't so hard to add esp if the annotation fits both an instance variable and a parameter in a constructor, like @Qualifier does.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

You can have a service defined like this:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeRouterService {

   @Qualifier("someDestination1") @NonNull private final SomeDestination someDestination1;
   @Qualifier("someDestination2") @NonNull private final SomeDestination someDestination2;

   public void onMessage(Message message) {
       // some code to route stuff based on something to either destination1 or destination2
   }

 }
```

Provided that you have a `lombok.config` file like this in the root of the project:

```
# Copy the Qualifier annotation from the instance variables to the constructor
# see https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/745
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
```

This was introduced in lombok 1.18.4, I wrote about it in my blogpost, and I am proud to say I was one of the main driving forces pushing for the implementation of the feature.

- The [blog post where the issue is discussed](https://ath3nd.wordpress.com/2018/12/13/spring-lombok-or-injection-just-became-a-bit-easier-part-2-of-2/) in detail
- The original [issue on github](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/745)
- And a small [github project to see it in action](https://github.com/lc-nyovchev/lombok-spring-qualifier)

Comment: I noticed that the `@Qualifier` part can come in-between `private final` and the interface. I prefer this as it keeps `private final` neatly aligned with auto-qualified counterparts.

Comment: Of course, it's just a matter of ordering and convention, however officially you'd put annotations before modifiers, or on a separate row: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838634/is-it-legal-to-put-annotation-after-access-modifier-in-java-7-or-java-8

Comment: works flawlessly!

Comment: Seems that you can use also `@Resource @NonNull private final SomeDestination someDestination1;` even without repeating of the variable name (since in your Qualifier example you need to mention variable name, so you have to type it twice). You don't need lombok.config in this case. (resource is `import javax.annotation.Resource;`).

Comment: @BojanVukasovic what you mention is similar to the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52540251 . The problem I see with this approach is that whether the code works depends on the variable name, which is what the original poster was trying to avoid by using the `@Qualifier` annotation and setting it there.

Comment: @NikolaYovchev yes, exactly. So instead repeating two times someDestination1 (in qualifier and variable name), why not have it only once as variable name... Less code is almost always better code.

Comment: @BojanVukasovic not sure if you got my point. Having injection depend on variable name is arguably worse than having to explicitly declare what actual  dependency you want based on the `@Qualifier` annotation (which is the purpose of the annotation). 

With what you propose, you save having to type the `@Qualifier` annotation, but injection will fail every time when somebody changes the variable name (without that being obvious until your test catches it, or worse, in prod), which is what the poster was trying to avoid.

Comment: @NikolaYovchev In that case, just use `@Resource(name="someDestination1")`. It will fail if someone changes the bean name and - you save yourself from adding lombok.config

Comment: @BojanVukasovic I am not sure if I get your proposal. `@Resource` can't be used on a constructor, only on fields, etc. The OP wanted to use **constructor** injection (which is the arguably best way of doing DI) AND `@Qualifier`. The original problem was `lombok` didn't copy/didn't have a way to copy the `@Qualifier` annotation on the generated constructor, but with the new `config` option introduced in `1.18.4`, it can do so. If I understood you wrong, maybe you can demonstrate a small repo with `@Resource` and constructor injection?

Comment: @NikolaYovchev yes, it cannot be set on constructor (and it will not be copied to constructor), but it works with constructor injection. At least this is what I see when I test it and manually decompile the generated class.

Comment: The code in this answer  works! and it failed after I use `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))?`...

Comment: @Ninja indeed, in the past, it was required to use `@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))` but nowadays `Spring` is smart enough so simply `@RequiredArgsConstructor` is sufficient.

Answer (score 41):

You may use spring trick to qualify field by naming it with desired qualifier without @Qualifier annotation.

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ValidationController {

  //@Qualifier("xmlFormValidator")
    private final Validator xmlFormValidator;
```

Comment: It doesn't work if used with @MockBean. Spring boot 2.2.5.RELEASE.

Comment: nice one, i like it

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me although I tried it

Answer (score 6):

I haven't test whether the accepted answer works well, but instead of create or edit lombok's config file, I think the cleaner way is rename the member variable to which name you want to qualifier.

```
// Error code without edit lombok config
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class Foo {
    @Qualifier("anotherDao") UserDao userDao;
}
```

Just remove @Qualifier and change your variable's name

```
// Works well
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class Foo {
    UserDao anotherDao;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is true, the field name is usually not something people aware will affect application behavior, and it may cause mysterious issues that are hard to detect.

Comment: @DavidBarda you are right from this perspective, thanks for your comment