# @AllArgsConstructor not working with spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, lombok, spring-annotations

I am having the class like below

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestController {

    @Qualifier("userDAO")
    private final Test testDAO;

}
```

Below is my bean registration

```xml
<bean id="userDAO" class="com.test.dao.TestImpl"
      p:sqlSessionFactory-ref="testSqlSessionFactory" />
```

when I run my app got error like below

```
No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException bean configuration
```

Also I tried to add the lombok.config file in root and copied the Qualifier annotation, that's also not helped.

spring version is 3.2.15. lombok version 1.18.16

It's working fine with below

```java
@Autowired
public TestController(@Qualifier("userDAO") final Test testDAO) {
    this.testDAO = testDAO;
}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: 'default constructor' refers to a constructor with __no__ args; the opposite of `@AllArgs`, as far as I know.

Comment: Just change `@AllArgsConstructor` to `@NoArgsConstructor` and the injection should work.

Comment: Did you took a look at this one, seems like very similar to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549657/is-it-possible-to-add-qualifiers-in-requiredargsconstructoronconstructor You can try quick fix that Алексей Виноградов proposed there or longer solution that is accepted answer.

Comment: I tried with lombok.config file with ```lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier```, that's also not worked

Comment: Adding only an `@AllArgsConstructor` isn't enough, as it will add the constructor **but** it doesn't add `@Autowired`. Because that is missing it will look for the default constructor. You also need to instruct lombok to add `@Autowired` to the constructor. Or upgrade to Spring 4.3 or higher which will automatically detect the single constructor and use it.

Comment: @M.Deinum Weird thing is, if my class impls an interface, then the auto detection that should work with Spring >= 4.3 doesnt work. If I remove the impl, then it works fine. Im using Spring Boot 2.7.3 and using Java 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding only an `@AllArgsConstructor` isn't enough, as it will add the constructor **but** it doesn't add `@Autowired`. Because that is missing Spring will look for the default constructor.

To fix you can do 1 of 3 things

1. Upgrade to Spring 4.3 or higher, as that will automatically use the single constructor and autowire it
2. Instruct lombok to add `@Autowired` to the constructor.
3. Ditch lombok and just provide the constructor yourself.

The first should be pretty easy (include a newer version of Spring in your dependencies). The second requires some additional code.

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class TestController {

    private final Test testDAO;

}
```

The `@Qualifier` won't work (and should be removed) as it should be on the constructor argument.

I would just ditch Lombok for this case and just add the constructor (option 3).

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class TestController {

    private final Test testDAO;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(@Qualifier("userDAO") Test testDao) {
        this.testDao=testDao;
    }
}
```