# Springboot dependency: two dependencies found and Qualifier ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

This is my class:

```java
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ServeiTerritorialCatalegsClientRepositoryImpl implements ServeiTerritorialCatalegsClientRepository {

    @Qualifier("catalegsMarshaller") private final Marshaller marshaller;

    //...
}
```

My bean definition is:

```java
@Bean
public Marshaller oidMarshaller() throws JAXBException {
   //...
}

@Bean
public Marshaller catalegsMarshaller() throws JAXBException {
  //...
}
```

I'm getting this message:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 3 of constructor in cat.catsalut.hes.mpi.hazelcast.loader.repository.ServeiTerritorialCatalegsClientRepositoryImpl required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - oidMarshaller: defined by method 'oidMarshaller' in class path resource [cat/catsalut/hes/mpi/hazelcast/loader/configuration/ServeiTerritorialConfiguration.class]
    - catalegsMarshaller: defined by method 'catalegsMarshaller' in class path resource [cat/catsalut/hes/mpi/hazelcast/loader/configuration/ServeiTerritorialConfiguration.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

Comment: I think it is due to RequiredArgsConstructor annotation. Because Lombok is not adding that Qualifier annotation within the constructor.

Comment: Seems to have an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50287955/5046887

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to do two things:

1. Update lombok.config and add this -

   lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
2. Use @Qualifier and provide a suitable unique name. Ex:

> ```
> @Repository
> @RequiredArgsConstructor
> @Slf4j
> public class MyImplClass{
>   @Qualifier("Myqualifier1") MyBean bean;
>  
>   Person getPerson()
> }
> ```

See lombok config guide here - [lombokconfig](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration)

Answer (score 0):

in class ServeiTerritorialCatalegsClientRepositoryImpl it seems there is a constructor whose 3rd parameter is of type Marshaller.
So while defining the parameter inside the constructor use qualifier ttribute for the paramter type Marshaller like below:

public ServeiTerritorialCatalegsClientRepositoryImpl(parameter1, paramter2, @Qualifier("catalegsMarshaller") Marshaller marshaller1)

Answer (score 0):

Lombok does not copy annotations from fields onto constructor parameters or property accessors. You'll need to provide the constructor yourself for now.