# Java annotation - What's the difference between putting it above method vs before return type

Tags: java, annotations

**Before return type:**

```
public @ResponseBody Map<Object, Object> search(@RequestParam(required = true) String q) {
```

**Above method:**

```
@ResponseBody
public Map<Object, Object> search(@RequestParam(required = true) String q) {
```

Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: See also the Java Language Specification on _method declarations_: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1

Comment: There is no difference, but convention is to place annotation in separate line. [Here is similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22838634/is-that-legal-to-put-annotation-after-access-modifier-in-java-7-or-java-8)

Comment: @xnor Oh I think I like that one better.

Comment: @xnor Your description is short and clear. I did search by google before ask question, but your link is not on the first page of search result, the link is also useful, thank you.