# What are the maximum number of modifiers, a java method can contain?

Tags: java, methods, modifiers

There are several modifiers used before declaring a java method such as `public`, `static`, `synchronized` etc.

I just want to know the maximum numbers of modifiers or all the combination of modifiers a java method can contain.

Comment: Read the [language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java modifiers syntax and format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050233/java-modifiers-syntax-and-format)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the Java language spec, [chapter 8.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4):

```
MethodDeclaration:
  {MethodModifier} MethodHeader MethodBody
```

and:

```
 MethodModifier:
 (one of) 
 Annotation public protected private 
 abstract static final synchronized native strictfp
```

You can't mix:

- the access modifiers (so you got one of those 3, or none for package protected)
- abstract, static, final
- abstract with (private, static, final, native, strictfp, synchronized)
- and finally: native and strictfp

Taking all of that together (thanks to user Andreas for the excellent wording):

Using regex syntax, we get to:

```
 [ public | protected | private] static final synchronized [native | strictfp]
```

So, the maximum number is 5; and 6 different combinations of those 5 keywords.

Comment: Some of them are mutually exclusive, so just listing them all doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Incomplete, since spec says "can't mix `abstract` with any of `private`, `static`, `final`, `native`, `strictfp`, or `synchronized`" and "can't mix `native`and `strictfp`".

Comment: So that leaves `[public | protected | private] static final synchronized [native | strictfp]`, i.e. answer is 5, and there are 6 combinations of that length.

Comment: Thanks for all that input; reworded again! Showed my gratitude elsewhere!

Comment: That is not regex syntax. Still, +1.

Comment: Hey, Ghost, someone downvoted [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43418203/5221149), and I'm wondering why. Can you see anything wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing that would explain a downvote. To the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Java spec, [§8.4.3. Method Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-MethodModifier), the total list of modifies are (not counting annotations):

> ```
> public protected private
> abstract static final synchronized native strictfp
> ```

`public`, `protected`, and `private` are mutually exclusive, though that section doesn't say that.

The spec also says:

> It is a compile-time error if a method declaration that contains the keyword `abstract` also contains any one of the keywords `private`, `static`, `final`, `native`, `strictfp`, or `synchronized`.

So if you include `abstract` that only leaves `public | protected`, so max of 2.

The next rule in the spec says:

> It is a compile-time error if a method declaration that contains the keyword `native` also contains `strictfp`.

So, this means that without `abstract`, you can mix as follows:

```
public | protected | private
static
final
synchronized
native | strictfp
```

Max length of 5, and there are 3 * 2 = 6 combinations with that length.

Comment: In a degenerate way, lack of any of the modifiers `public`, `protected`, or `private` on a member is a modifier, the "default" or "package-private" phantom access modifier.

Comment: @LewBloch I disagree. The word "modifier" means that it modifies something. In this case, a method is package-private, unless a modifier changes it. As such, package-private is not a modifier, it's the default value/state. Note that there are no modifier keywords for specifying the default state, e.g. `virtual` for opposite of `final`. All the keywords truly *are* modifiers.

Comment: Note: "In a degenerate way". You're correct, of course, but ironically, in practice "default" access is not the default. People have to make a conscious choice to use default access, if they're actually programming. Most seem to understand `public`, `protected`, and `private` well enough. Package-private has its engineering purposes​ and is on an equal footing with the others, except when it comes to having its own keyword.